# Get Text from strange <i> tag in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I want to get text (_reserve0|uint112 :  80540710293008523149) from these  tags . check image.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFgW7.png)

I'm getting only the first text value (_reserve0|uint112).
My code:

```
reserve_unit0 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='readCollapse8']/div/form/div/i[4]")
print(reserve_unit0.text)
```

I tried this code but still, I get only "_reserve0|uint112"

```
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#readCollapse8 > div > form > div > i:nth-child(8)")))).strip())
```

Comment: Try it once and check `get_attribute("innerText")` without using `i` index or share you url

Comment: Thank you!! it worked. I am getting text without using get_attribute. i just ignored <I> tags. `//*[@id='readCollapse8']/div/form/div` 

i want to ignore 1st line of text. is it possible???

`reserve0 uint112, _reserve1 uint112, _blockTimestampLast uint32
  _reserve0|uint112 :  80599766478675242983
  _reserve1|uint112 :  185085206145735796854894
  _blockTimestampLast|uint32 :  1627461284`